# Когда правильно говорить "человек", а когда "людей" во мн. ч. род. падежа?

Tags: выбор-слов, орфография, сравнение, правила

От чего зависит выбор между "человек" и "людей"? Почему, согласно НКРЯ, в последнее время "двух людей" (без прилагательных и чего-то еще, именно "двух людей") употребляется чаще, чем "двух человек"? И почему "двух людей" употребляется чаще, чем "трех людей" и "четырех людей"?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: Услышала сегодня в программе местного телевидения(твк, Красноярск): " В аварии получили травмы около 20 людей". Слух режет. Интуитивно чувствую: не то.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Человек" во множественном числе свойственно "обезличивающему" контексту, в котором это слово - единица измерения количества людей при указанном числе. Например, в случае числа "2" возможны разные ситуации, в которых предпочтительны свои варианты человек/людей:

> У двух человек из числа спасённых альпинистов зафиксированы
>   обморожения.

(важна статистика)

> У этих двух людей сложились тёплые отношения.

(важен личностный аспект; то же было бы в случае трёх или четырёх только что представленных людей)

Почему чаще встречается "трёх *человек*"? Возможно, потому, что бОльшие числа чаще требуются в отвлечённом от личности "количественном" смысле.

Comment: Насколько помню, "двое людей" допустимо только с прилагательными ("двое молодых людей"), хотя и эта форма сейчас вытесняется "двумя человеками". Если покажете мне, что я неправ, буду весьма признателен. .

Comment: Косвенное подтверждение. http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/59.htm §167. Употребление собирательных числительных

Comment: Я не употреблял "двое людей" или "двоих людей", да и в вопросе не было этого "группового" аспекта.

Comment: Но "двух-то людей" вы употребили?

Comment: Да, причём в смысле, противоположном счётному, и в родительном падеже, о котором спрашивалось. Как вы предложили бы изменить мой второй пример? Из первой попавшейся книжки (изд. прайм-ЕВРОЗНАК 2003, что-то астрологическое): Мышь - Коза. У этих двух людей общего столько же, сколько и противоречий. Страница: https://books.google.ru/books?id=nDyFxW7lb6sC&hl=ru&pg=PA103&img=1&zoom=3&ots=lvOkl5jHAv&sig=ACfU3U0JdOTxBa92_ECAfA2guLPDIczNOw&w=1280

Comment: Из литературоведческого текста по Достоевскому: Однако ж, можно догадаться, «знакомство и дружество» этих двух людей завязалось надолго.
http://www.fedordostoevsky.ru/works/characters/Radomsky_E_P/

Comment: Я уже сформулировал свое отношение в отдельном ответе.

Answer (score 4):

У вас немножко неправильно формулируется.
Давайте так. Множественное число - это множественное число. Для человека -  всегда люди.

А вот при числительных - разговор особый. Там используется т. н. счетная форма. Та же форма множественного числа в родительном падеже используется как счетная при числительных на пять, шесть и т. д.

А вот при числительных два, три, четыре (и тех, что на них оканчиваются)   она в основном совпадает с родительным **единственного** (исторически это особая форма двойственного числа).

Не путайте.

Теперь непосредственно по вопросу.

Люди - множественное для "человек". Ну а во множественном числе - люди. Никаких "человеков".

Счетная же форма для слова "человек" такая: один **человек**; два, три, четыре **человека**, пять, шесть (и т. д.) **человек**. "Людей" здесь будет  ошибкой.

Так что это особое слово, надо просто принять и запомнить.
Еще надо уяснить счетную форму для слова "год".
*Один год, два года*, но *пять лет*.

Все остальные слова в русском образуют счетные формы регулярно, по общему правилу.

Answer (score 3):

Дополнение к ответу.
Не хватает места в комментариях процитировать.

В отношении допустимости форм "двоих людей" и "двух людей".

Я в корне не согласен с @Alex_ander, предлагающим "двух людей".
По мне **обе** эти формы неправильны, каким бы контекстом мы не оперировали.

> Примечание 2. В сочетании с числ. пять, шесть (и далее) слово человек
> во всех падежах выступает в формах мн. ч., образованных от основы
> человек-, а не от супплетивной основы форм мн. ч. лю|д'|-: человек,
> человекам, человеками, о человеках (пять человек, с семью человеками).
> ***В сочетании с числ. два, оба, три, четыре перечисленные словоформы мн.
> ч. выступают во всех падежных формах, кроме формы им. п. (не было и
> двух человек, речь идет о трех человеках).*** При сочетании с формой им.
> п. этих числительных выступает словоформа род. п. ед. ч. (два
> человека, три человека, оба человека). При наличии определения в
> сочетаниях с числ. пять, шесть (и далее) во всех падежах и с числ.
> два, три, четыре в косв. пад. может употребляться слово люди: пять
> незнакомых человек и пять незнакомых людей, не было и трех взрослых
> человек и не было и трех взрослых людей.

[ИМЯ ЧИСЛИТЕЛЬНОЕ | rusgram.narod.ru](http://rusgram.narod.ru/1366-1383.html)
Русская грамматика, § 1371.
(*курсив мой - b-s*).

Таким образом, как я и помнил, ***в сочетании с два, три и четыре без слова-определения во всех падежах возможна только форма "два, три, четыре человека"***.

Comment: Исключите, пожалуйста, упоминание о "двоих людях" применительно к моему ответу (там такого не было).

Comment: В примере из аргументирующей цитаты речь идёт о подсчёте неназванных людей. Литературный пример с людьми более конкретными. Николай Огарёв (С того берега, 1858; Избранное, 1977)
И все жаль мне их — этих двух людей,
Что сложили свои головы...
http://www.world-art.ru/lyric/lyric.php?id=10069

Comment: Не вижу причин что либо "исключать". Максимум - могу уточнить, (что уже и сделал). Что у вас было, и так видно по Вашему ответу. А я с ним не согласен. Чем блох ловить, лучше дайте ссылку источник, где излагается это разделение по линии конкретных людей и абстрактных "человеков". Это действительно было бы интересно и содержательно. А вопрос "двух"/"двоих" - это вообще-то отдельная тема.

Comment: Цитату полуторавековой давности мне трудно комментировать. Мне сам текст Огарева представляется стилизацией под патриархальность со всеми возможными нарушениями грамматики.. Не читал, хотя дома книжка стояла, не осилил.

Comment: Я обязательно попытаюсь найти теоретическое подкрепление, но вот какая сейчас попалась на "Грамоте" (редакционная?) статья "Типология ошибок", с анализом ошибок у журналистов. Там есть два случая употребления "двух людей" (поиском по странице находится): один - в тексте журналиста (критикуется стилистическая ошибка, а это словосочетание оставлено автором без внимания), другой - в речи самого автора, при толковании рассматриваемого им текста. http://www.gramota.ru/biblio/research/rubric_370/rubric_388/ Или это не слишком авторитетный источник?

Comment: Трудности русского языка: словарь-справочник, изд. 4-е; Авторы: Владимир Вакуров,Людмила Рахманова,Илья Толстой,Наталья Формановская ("Наука", 2011). Не из тематической статьи, тем не менее, устами авторов этого труда (об употреблении слова "тандем" стр. 543): ... (совместность усилий двух людей, коллективов) https://books.google.ru/books?id=UVllAAAAQBAJ&hl=ru&pg=PA543&img=1&zoom=3&ots=EBoPQjjaYe&sig=ACfU3U1Cz_H2sronmnytO5PUE-UB0pzNPw&w=1280

Comment: Из книги "Лексические трудности в изучении русского языка" (Розанова, Шустикова, "Наука", 2009 стр. 15: учебный пример по другому поводу): "Из двух людей с одинаковым опытом тот, кто лучше осмысливает свои впечатления...)" https://books.google.ru/books?id=4VDTAAAAQBAJ&hl=ru&pg=PA15&img=1&zoom=3&ots=WRWVDgxnUs&sig=ACfU3U2lSUTHXIjIWTeR-il97UiLZ3CEJw&w=1280

Answer (score 2):

> Почему, согласно НКРЯ, в последнее время "двух людей" (без
>   прилагательных и чего-то еще, именно "двух людей") употребляется чаще,
>   чем "двух человек"?

То, что сочетания ***"двух людей", "двум людям",  "о двух людях"*** абсолютно корректны, у меня никаких сомнений не вызывает. Так говорили и раньше:

**Лев Толстой:** *Кому **из двух людей** лучше: тому ли, кто сам своим трудом себя кормит…*

**Пешковский:** *Хотя здесь подлежащего нет. и нельзя даже сказать, что оно "подразумевается", потому что произнесшие эту фразу не держали, вероятно, в уме ни имен этих **двух людей**, ни…*

**Дмитрий Лихачёв:** *Опишите внешность **двух людей**, литературных героев или ваших товарищей, которых вы считаете антиподами.*

**Корней Чуковский:** *Я уверен, что какой-нб. кофейник — гораздо больше мешает **двум людям** порвать свою постылую жизнь, чем боязнь сплетен…*

**Он же:** *На ней лежит забота только **о двух людях**...*

**Константин Паустовский:** *Мысль **о двух людях**, спасенных им, будет жить в сердцах...*

Такие сочетания встречаются и во многих сегодняшних книгах по языкознанию, написанных отнюдь не неграмотными людьми. К примеру, здесь:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Или в словаре-справочнике **Вакурова** и др. *("Трудности русского языка")*, который упомянул в своём комментарии в этой теме и *Alex_ander:*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Или в разных книгах у **Розенталя**:

> *Глаза этих **двух людей**, встретившись, говорили друг другу многое...*
>
> *Все почему-то обрадовались нежданной встрече **двух людей**, знакомых, возможно, еще с незапамятных довоенных времен.*

И, по-моему, не во всех из приведённых выше примеров целесообразно употребление (вместо форм слова *люди*) косвенных падежей мн. ч. *человек,  человекам, человеками,  о человеках.* Вряд ли кто будет уж очень сильно настаивать на том, что *"мешает двум людям"* или *"на ней лежит забота только о двух людях"* звучит хуже, чем *"мешает двум человекам"* или *"на ней лежит забота только о двух человеках"*. Я бы, во всяком случае, не стал этого делать...